# Why not write changes directly to the output register?

Tags: verilog

I am very new to verilog. I found this pwm code:

```
module pwm #(parameter CTR_LEN = 8) (
 input clk,
 input rst,
 input [CTR_LEN - 1 : 0] compare,
 output pwm
);

reg pwm_d, pwm_q;
reg [CTR_LEN - 1: 0] ctr_d, ctr_q;

assign pwm = pwm_q;

always @(*) begin
 ctr_d = ctr_q + 1'b1;

 if (compare > ctr_q)
  pwm_d = 1'b1;
 else
  pwm_d = 1'b0;
end

always @(posedge clk) begin
 if (rst) begin
  ctr_q <= 1'b0;
 end else begin
  ctr_q <= ctr_d;
 end

 pwm_q <= pwm_d;
end

endmodule
```

(source: embeddedmicro.com)

I don't understand why there are two always blocks. And why the doubled registers?
Why not have only one counter and pwm register, only the posedge block and directly manipulate the registers? Like that:

```
module pwm #(parameter CTR_LEN = 8) (
 input clk,
 input rst,
 input [CTR_LEN - 1 : 0] compare,
 output pwm
);

reg pwm;
reg [CTR_LEN - 1: 0] ctr;

always @(posedge clk) begin
 if (rst) begin
  ctr = 1'b0;
 end else begin
  ctr = ctr + 1'b1;
 end

 if (compare > ctr)
  pwm = 1'b1;
 else
  pwm = 1'b0;
end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is part coding style preference, part coding style best practices, and a bit of how a synthesizer will optimize.
You could write it as one always block as follows (different to what you provided):

```
module pwm #(parameter CTR_LEN = 8) (
 input clk,
 input rst,
 input [CTR_LEN - 1 : 0] compare,
 output reg pwm // Note the 'reg'
);

//reg pwm; // You cannot define pwm on separate lines as output and reg with ANSI style
reg [CTR_LEN - 1: 0] ctr;

always @(posedge clk) begin
 if (rst) begin
  ctr <= 1'b0; // use non-blocking ('<='), instead of blocking ('=')
 end else begin
  ctr <= ctr + 1'b1; // use non-blocking ('<='), instead of blocking ('=')
 end

 if (compare > ctr) 
  pwm <= 1'b1; // use non-blocking
 else
  pwm <= 1'b0; // use non-blocking
end

endmodule
```

Best practice:

1. Use non-blocking (`<=`) to assign flops and latches.

   - This removes a race condition in the Verilog simulation scheduler, no impact on synthesis. If you do not use non-blocking then the functional behavior between simulation and circuit could be different. Non-blocking are evaluated immediately but are the new values are not applied until after all operations are completed in the same stamp. This means every time a flop is sampled it will always be the value not before the clock, not the new value.
2. Use blocking (`=`) to assign combinational logic.

   - Combinational logic needs to be evaluated and updated immediately.
3. Pure combinational logic should be in a separate always block from flops

   - If one always block, incomplete combinational logic will be converted to synchronous logic. This wastes area and flops and is very hard to find.
   - If two always blocks, incomplete combinational logic will infer latches; often complex latches. Latches are less ideal that flops, however linting tools, synthesis tools, and logical equivalency checking tools typically give warnings about latches. These warnings are a way of finding unintended inferred latches.
     Note: SystemVerilog added a keywords to identify intended combinational logic (`always_comb` block) and intended latches (`always_latch` block).
4. It is recommended not to put flops with reset/set (especially asynchronous reset/set) in the same always block that doesn't have reset/set.

   - Some synthesizers will use same flop type with the with the set/reset timed to a constant, which can be a waste of area since this flops are typically bigger.
5. The outputs of a module with sequential logic (flops) should be flops.

   - This rule has to do with timing. It is easier to predict the combinational latency in a module.
     For example `assign pwm = (compare >= ctr);` would add additional delay and noise (after synthesis) to downstream modules that receive `pwm` as an input. As a flop, the output signal is clean.

Some designers take #3 to a higher purity and move all the calculations for the flop into a combinational block. The sequential block (always block with a clock) is simplified to simple assignments and reset (and sometimes set) logic. Advantages for doing this:

1. For large code, this reduces the total lines of code.
2. It allows a way see the flops current value and next value, as they are separate signals.
3. Some ASIC designer find this style is easier to apply manual error corrections to a silicon mask.
4. Synthesizer that do advance logic optimization tend to generate better results with the two always block structure. This is critical when trying to meet timing as sizing requirements.

The only disadvantage is a few more lines in small modules. A negligible price to pay for a uniform coding style on a typical project.

I prefer not assigning flops directly to output wires (ex: `assign pwm = pwm_q;`). The only case I like to use it is when it makes connectivity easier. Granted the author wanted to maintain a `_d` (input of flop) `_q` (output of flop) coding style. I personally would have gone with a simple `pwm` (and `ctr`) for the flop output name and `next` or `ns` as a suffix or prefix. But that is just coding style difference.

The wire output approach does have one advantage. If two module happen to drive `pwm`, the you will see an X when the values conflict. As `output reg` The X is only visible in the parent module. Linting and synthesis will give warnings or errors for this. It is only a visual check in verilog simulation.

If you truly want to guaranty one driver one a flop output at simulation time, then it is better to enable SystemVerilog and use `output logic pwm` with `pwm` being assigned in an `always_ff` block. `always_ff`, `always_comb`, and `always_latch` throw errors at compile/elaboration time if any other block is also assigning there respected left-hand side values.

Answer (score 2):

**Why double registers?**

First of all, when you declare something as `reg`, it need not generate a storage element like flip flop or latch in hardware. The synthesize tool will use combinational login if possible.

```
always @(*) begin
 ctr_d = ctr_q + 1'b1;

 if (compare > ctr_q)
  pwm_d = 1'b1;
 else
  pwm_d = 1'b0;
end
```

In the above code, `always@(*)` means to evaluate the block immediately whenever any of the inputs to the enclosed expressions change. Here `ctr_d` is calculated immediately whenever `ctr_q` change. Therefore `ctr_d` is just the adder output, no storage elements needed. similarly, `pwm_d` is evaluated whenever `ctr_q` or `compare` change. This is just the comparator output, again, no storage elements needed. For both `pwm_d` and `ctr_d`, the synthesize tool will generate only combinational logic.

Now, if you don't have the `else` part for `pwm_d`, the tool will make an "inferred latch" for it so that when the `if` statement is false, `pwm_d` will retain its old value.

If you want to want to be more explicit, you can replace the `always @(*)` block with the following.

```
wire [CTR_LEN - 1: 0] ctr_d;
wire pwd_d;

assign ctr_d = ctr_q + 1'b1;
assign pwm_d = (compare > ctr_q)? 1'b1 : 1'b0; // Ternary operator
```

**First code is better.**

In the first code, at clock edge both `ctr_d` and `pwm_d` are ready, you just have to push them to `ctr_q` and `pwm_q`. where as in your code, at clock edge, you start computing `ctr = ctr+1'b1`. then you compare and finally `pwm` is changed. So in the second code, after clock edge there will be adder delay and comparator delay before `pwm` changes.